# JQuery Ajax send data from form not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My script should prevent the page to be refreshed or redirected, but when i click submit button it redirects me.

Error Message from JavaScript console

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val(...).len is not a function

myScript.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "Ready!" );
    //Submitting the form data
    $("#user-form").submit(function(e){
        if($('#fName').val().len() != "" && $('#lName').val().len() != "" && $('#nickname').val().len() != "") {
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "user-process.php",
               data: $("#user-form").serialize(),
               success: function(data){
                   $('#user-form')[0].reset();
                   console.log(data); // show response from the php script.
               }
             });
         }
         else {
             alert("Please fill the fields.")
         }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    setInterval(function(){ $(`#table`).load('info.php #table'); }, 1000); //Loading table data without refreshing page.

});
```

Comment: Take a look at [JavaScript String length](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"len()" is not a javascript function, you can modify your code to be :

```
if( $('#fName').val() && $('#lName').val() && $('#nickname').val() )
```

and will work

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .length instead of .len()
https://api.jquery.com/length/

Answer (score 0):

`val()` returns a string. Strings don’t have `.len()` function. Also, since you’re comparing it with another string, you don’t need to get length, just use this:

```
    if($('#fName').val() != "" && $('#lName').val() != "" && $('#nickname').val() != "") {
```

If you want to check length, you can get it using `.length`. But then you should compare it with `0`, not with `""`:

```
    if($('#fName').val().length != 0 && $('#lName').val().length != 0 && $('#nickname').val().length != 0) {
```

Things like `$('#fName').val().length != ""` would technically work, because JavaScript will convert `""` into `0` for you, but it’s a bad coding practice, as it makes the code hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

To know if a string is empty or not, you can use the following statements :

- `$(selector).val() !== ''`
- `!$(selector).val().length`
- `$(selector).val().length === 0`

(Since a string length will never be negative, the two last ones are equal)

About the redirection fact, take a look at the stopPropagation and stopImmediatePropagation functions

https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/
https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, `String` object don't have `len()` function, instead they have `length` property.

Usage:

```
var myString = "Hello";
console.log(myString.length); // returns 5
```